# Mikro-ORM nullable for ManyToMany property PostgreSQL

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, option-type, nullable, mikro-orm

I'm new to the MikroORM framework and can't seem to figure this one out.

I try to create an object where the `roles` property on account is optional. There is a `@ManyToMany` relationship between role and account. But only when I manually set `roles` to `[]` on `Account` I can store the object.

I also tried to set a default value as in `[]` in the property declaration without success. I think it tries to insert the Collection item object to the database.

```
insert into "account_roles" ("account_id", "role_id") values (1, '[object Object]') returning "account_id", "role_id" - invalid input syntax for type integer: "[object Object]"
```

Can you guys help me out? Or point me where this is noted in the docs. Thanks!

**Account**

```
@Entity()
export class Account {
    @PrimaryKey()
    @Unique()
    id: number;

    //...

    @Property({onCreate: () => new Date()})
    createdAt: Date = new Date();

    @Property({onUpdate: () => new Date() })
    modifiedAt: Date = new Date();

    @IsOptional()
    @ManyToMany({ entity: () => Role, nullable: true})
    roles = new Collection<Role>(this);

}
```

**Role**

```
@Entity()
export class Role {

    @PrimaryKey()
    @Unique()
    id: number;

    @Property()
    name: string;

}
```

Comment: Collections cannot be nullable, they dont represent any database column.

Comment: But I can’t seem to set a default empty array, though I can assign an empty array during creation. Is there a way to set a default empty array value?

Comment: its not an array, its a collection of items. if you dont assign any items, it is empty

Comment: Sorry, my global pipeline config did something that it didn't need to do. Thanks for the quick help @MartinAdámek!